# How to have a slider bar add or subtract elements dynamically on a website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am coming into this as a bit of a philistine so bear with me... I have recently started learning to code after coming up with an idea for a website, and decided to try and make it myself.

So on the site I have made a page which will be used to display an array of buttons, representing availability, and therefore have two states: *clicked* or *un-clicked*. Each user, once logged-in, will have to choose their own amount of buttons to display from a slider menu ranging from 1-100.

In order to do this I think I will have to design an individual .html file with 1 button, 2 buttons, 3 buttons etc etc... and have each of these files match up with the corresponding amount selected.

Since I plan to have up to 100 buttons I can imagine that this will not only take a long time but could possibly slow my site down quite a lot.

Is there a way to have just one .html file and have it dynamically update itself relative to the number selected by the user through Javascript or PHP?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do such a thing, sounds like you would be wanting to use AJAX to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding, you want to choose the # of buttons to display from a slider, and have a single page update itself relative to the number of buttons to display. I'm not sure what you mean by clicked/unclicked.

Here is a form to select the number of buttons to display from a range input slider. On submit, I grab the value from the slider, and loop through that in a javascript array, creating buttons. Is that generally what you're going for?

- Note, I did have a form in this code, but removed it because the code editor gave an error saying 'allow-forms' permission isn't set, so I assigned a click handler to the submit button instead of using a proper form.

```js
$('#range').on('change',function(){
  $('#rangeVal').html($(this).val());
});

$('#submit').on('click',function() {
  rangeVal = $('#range').val();
  $buttons = $('#buttons');
  $buttons.html('');
  for (var i = 1; i <= rangeVal; i++) {
    $buttons.append('<svg id="table1" width="250" height="300"> <circle id="seat" cx="170" cy="125" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" onclick="changeColor()"/>');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="range" min="1" max="100" id="range" value="1"> <span id="rangeVal">1</span> 
<input type="submit" id="submit">

<div id="buttons"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I realise now I was a little vague on what I meant by buttons, I have created a 'button' from an <svg> element                             (here is the code <svg id="table1" width="250" height="300">
  <circle id="seat" cx="170" cy="125" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" onclick="changeColor()" />)                                                                                     so my idea is that when the slider shows 1 there is one svg present, when its at 100 there are 100 svgs present on the page.

Comment: @AndyFinn are you able to adapt what I did to use  svg's or do you still need hlep? You should just be able to put your svg code where I have the button code.

Comment: Yes I would need help with that thank you, as when I put it on my site only the slider appears, and the number stays at 1, without any buttons or svgs appearing.

Comment: @AndyFinn ok I updated the code in my answer, but I literally copied and pasted it from your comment with no changes.

Comment: Alright thank you very much for your help!